# Mean value theorem and bounded function

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Let $h : [0,a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable, $h'(0) = h(0) = 0$ and $|h''(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in [0,a].$ Show $|h(x)| \leq \frac{Mx^2}{2}$ for all $x \in [0,a]$

Here's what I have so far, but it's missing something: For any $x \in [0,a]$, the mean value theorem tells us that there exists a $c \in (0,x)$ with $|h''(c)| = |\frac{h'(x) - h'(0)}{x-0}| \implies |h'(x)| \leq Mx$. There also exists a $d\in(0,x)$ with $|h'(d)| = |\frac{h(x) - h(0)}{x-0}| \implies |h(x)| \leq Mx^2$. Now I don't understand where the 2 in the denominator is supposed to come from. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Using Taylor Series:

$h(x)=h(0)+xh^{'}(0)+\frac{x^2}{2}h^{''}(0)+\ldots$

Comment: Do you know of a way to do it using the mean value theorem? This is for a class and that's what we're supposed to use.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to do it with MVT:

Disclaimer: in the following, $x$ is constant and differentiation is with respect to $t$

For **constant** $0<x\leq a$, define:

$g(t)=h(t)+h'(t)(x-t)+\xi(x-t)^2-h(x)$

Now we have:

$g(0)=\xi x^2-h(x)$

$g(x)=h(x)-h(x)=0$

So if we chose $\xi=\frac{h(x)}{x^2}$ we have $g(0)=g(x)=0$

By MVT there exists $c\in(0,x)$ such that $g'(c)=0$

But $g'(t)=h'(t)+h''(t)(x-t)-h'(t)-2\xi (x-t)=(x-t)(h''(t)-2\xi)$

So $\xi=\frac{h''(c)}{2}$

Plug $\xi$ in the equation $g(0)=0$ and get $0=\frac{h''(c)}{2} x^2=h(x)$

So $|h(x)|=\frac{|h''(c)|}{2} x^2\le \frac{M}{2}x^2$

which is what you wanted. Kind of messy, but it is what you want.

Comment: You aren't using MVT, you're using Rolle's Theorem, which kind of seems like beating around the bush since your choice of g comes from something that looks like the first couple of terms of the Taylor series.